# Integration for exponential

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Prove that $$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x} e^{t^{2}}  d t=0$$

What is the main intuition to tackle this problem? I tried to utilize all the possible theorems, including Taylor's theorem and other related ones, but all of them turned out to be in vain. How could possibly tackle the initial idea for such a seemingly easy exercise?

Comment: Hint : express it as a ratio of an integral over an exponential expression, and use L'Hopital's.

Comment: L'Hopital's is the usual way to deal with this kind of problems

Comment: I would use the FTA. Write the integral as $F(x)-F(0)$ and observe that the limit is thus $\dfrac{F(x)}{F'(x)}-\dfrac{F(0)}{F'(x)}.$

Comment: Just s quick question: In order to utilize L'Hopital's rule, should not we prove the existence of the derivative of the integral in the numerator? Oh, it seems that according to the continuity of $e^{t^2}$, we can deduce that the integral can be differentiable. Nice!

Comment: @MariusS.L. Could you please suggest how could you proceed with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus or the L'Hopital's rule?!

Comment: @Tortar So basically, one needs to take the derivative of the numerator which will output the original function of $e^{t^2}$?!

Comment: @Snowflake I added an answer :-)

Comment: @Tortar Genius!

Comment: @Snowflake For the sake of completion: The expression goes to $L:=F(x)/F'(x)$ for $x\to\infty .$ Assume $L\neq 0,$ then de L'Hôpital says $F'(x)/F''(x) = e^{x^2}/2xe^{x^2}=1/(2x) \neq 0$ for $x \to \infty $ which is not true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'Hopital's rule gives a one-liner proof of the equality. If you are determined to avoid this powerful machinery, however, then we can still prove this relatively easily.

Consider $x > 0$. Then

\begin{align*}
0
\leq e^{-x^2} \int_{0}^{x} e^{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t
= \int_{0}^{x} e^{-(x-t)(x+t)} \, \mathrm{d}t
\leq \int_{0}^{x} e^{-(x-t)x} \, \mathrm{d}t
= \frac{1 - e^{-x^2}}{x}.
\end{align*}

So by the squeezing lemma, the limit is zero as desired.

Comment: Brilliant squeezing and very mind-blowing solution! Well Done!

Comment: Honestly, I am becoming intrigued on how one can apply L'Hopital's rule here? Is the derivative of integral on the numerator becomes a very obvious value?

Answer (score 3):

One can write that
$$ \int_0^xe^{t^2}dt\leqslant xe^{x^2} $$
but the upper bound is not $o(e^{x^2})$. To solve this issue, we need an upper bound of $t\mapsto e^{t^2}$ that will be a $o(xe^{x^2})$, for instance something like $e^{x^2-x^{\alpha}}$ with $\alpha\in]0,2[$. To do so, you can reduce the upper bound of the integral, but you need to make sure that the second part will still be negligeable, beside having an upper bound in the integral that is not $o(e^{x^2})$. To make sure this does not happen, it suffices to let the interval of integration going to $0$. We can summarize this as follow :
$$ \int_0^{x}e^{t^2}dt=\int_0^{x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}e^{t^2}dt+\int_{x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}^x e^{t^2}dt\leqslant \left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)e^{x^2-2\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}e^{x^2} $$
Therefore
$$ e^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt\leqslant e^{-2\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

Answer (score 1):

One liner with l'Hopital's

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_{0}^{x} e^{t^{2}} d t}{e^{x^2}} \: \stackrel{\text{l'Hop.}}{=} \: \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{x^{2}} }{2xe^{x^2}}= \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2x} =0$$

Comment: Whoah, genius! FTC had dominated the question! I guess the ability to use L'Hopital's rule was the continuity of the given exponential function. This helped us a lot to condense the solution for short proof.